# Dropdown Menu not displaying properly in ie7 or ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am currently working on a project and I am having problems with the dropdown menu and how it is displaying in ie7 and ie8.

You can view it here:

http://getsmarta.co/_cms/topflight/

Here is the css I am using:

```
 nav {  width:1026px;
height: 50px;
background-image:url(../img/nav.png);
padding:0 0px 0 0px;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:30px;
```

}

```
nav ul li  {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
```

}

```
nav ul li div.sub {
display:none;
position:absolute;
background-color:#003e88;
top:38px;
width:260px;
text-align:left;
border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
-o-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
-khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
```

}

```
nav ul li div.sub a{
background-image:none;
```

}

```
nav li a {
padding:13px 20px 11px 20px;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:-10px;
background-image:url(../img/nav-divider.png);
background-position:top right;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
font-family:champ, myriad, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
margin-right:-4px;
```

}

```
nav li a:hover {border: 0;
background-image:url(../img/hover.png);
```

}

```
nav li.current a {
color:#47cacd;
```

}

I am at a loss with it and any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, your dropdown shows up behind the links on the left and picture of the chair lift in Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is much simpler then that, IE for some reason is not accepting your `display:inline-block` declaration for your menu nav items. Though you can fix it by targeting your `nav` menu in IE by using the `.oldie` class provided by the html5-boilerplate and setting it to `float:left` instead, so try this in your CSS:

```
.oldie nav li {
  float:left;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

By the way, you need to declare a `z-index` value to your nav elements as well in order for them to appear on top of everything else, try this:

```
nav ul li {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed it.  I have been trying to figure it out for ages.
I also noticed I was able to do it by using a star infront, I don't know whether this is a good way of doing it, for example:

nav ul li {
*float:left;
}

Comment: @SuziLarsen the star hack will target only target certain versions of IE i believe and its really not needed when you have a universal class to target older browsers, so i would recommend that approach for a hack-free stylesheet. Also, if the answer satisfied your question please mark it as correct by ticking the green checkmark for easier classification and search for future posters.

Comment: thankyou so much, I am using the universal class like you said and it is working great. I have marked your answer as correct also, I am new to the site so still a little green at the moment. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think HTML 5 elements are not supported in IE, if you put a DIV with a ID of nav and put your all CSS on it, it will work.
If you want to use HTML5 then there are javascript hacks which can help you :)